# Move control to different line in Chrome Debugger Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging in JavaScript line in chrome developer tools, how can I move the control back to a few lines above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround that may fit your needs (if the code doesn't have a lot of side effects) is to set a breakpoint on the desired line and make a small yet meaningful change to your current function using LiveEdit. This way, the affected call frame(s) will be discarded from the call stack and the respective functions re-invoked, breaking at the necessary line.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. But as you must have also experienced, this need comes when either you have passed the line which you want to again execute or when you know that the next line will throw an error and you want to skip it because at that moment you are interested in executing the lines after it and not the breaking line.

Comment: Correct, but as far as I know, only MS Visual Studio allows setting an IP to an arbitrary code line, alas :( If you desperately need this capability, file a feature request at http://new.crbug.com (mention DevTools in the summary line), even though it's not likely to get a high priority.

Comment: Thanks very much @Alexander. Added feature request http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107353&thanks=107353&ts=1323785113.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it will answer your question directly, but there is a pretty good video covering the Chrome Dev tools, in particular new features on Paul Irish's site:

http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Thanks @Ira, I know how to use Chrome Dev tools. I wanted to know how to achieve this particular thing in Chrome Dev tools.

Answer (score -3):

I guess chrome doest care to fix stuff that is less good than Internet Explorer. quite disappointing.. why do so many developers think chrome is good. I find it very frustrating that it is almost impossible to do things like dynamically change the javascript which would remove the need to redeploy .js files to the server to test one simple change.

Comment: Does this answer the question asked above? Stackoverflow is not like other forums where one can say anything anywhere on any topic. You might want to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/conduct and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer